# How to connect multiple wireless peripherals through a usb hub

Tags: usb-hub, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, hub, peripherals

My laptop only has 2 usb ports so I use a simple hub to plug in my wireless mouse and keyboard (two separate connections) and my wireless headphones.

The mouse and headphones are useable most of the time with just a slight jerkiness. But once I plug something into the third port in my hub, whether a usb or the charging wire for my headphones, everything stops working. The mouse won't move and the keyboard types every tenth letter.

I did a little research on this but I'm seriously confused between hub charging power, laptop usb power, Selective Suspension, and 2.0 vs 3.0 vs C.

- What do I need in order for my peripherals to work and preferably be able to charge my headphones at the same time as well?
- How can I check how much power each device uses?
- How can I check how much power the laptop supplies to the usb port?

(Since I work away from my desk at regular intervals, it would be great if the solution were portable and not mains powered. However from what I've seen so far this may be pushing things...)

Answer (score 0):

The USB hub is connected to a USB port for supplying power
(and other services).
You might be coming up against the maximum amount of power that your port
can supply.

You could do the following :

- Connect the hub to a USB 3.0 port
  (if one is available and the hub is currently connected to USB 2.0 port)
- Get a self-powered hub (meaning one that connects to the mains power).